# How I make pytorch read the numpy format?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I'm trying to create a code with PyTorch and Keras that uses the BERT algorithm to detect fake news, but I got an error tells me:

```
can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.bool_.
The only supported types are: double, float, float16, int64, int32, and uint8.
```

Please access the code on my [Google Codelab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1j7LMiatdR95TgYx10JFXgprOzb-qbOFu). The error can be seen in the last cell.

The only requirement for running it is downloading a [CSV](https://www.kaggle.com/mrisdal/fake-news) file for the training process.

Answer (score 3):

I can't confirm but I believe your problem will be solved by changing:

```
train_y = np.array(train_labels) == 'fake'
test_y = np.array(test_labels) == 'fake'
```

to:

```
train_y = (np.array(train_labels) == 'fake').astype(int)
test_y = (np.array(test_labels) == 'fake').astype(int)
```

The train_y data is currently an array of type Bool (True or False) and the tensor needs and int (0 or 1).

Comment: I got an error called: name 'device' is not defined can you fix that for me, please.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1j7LMiatdR95TgYx10JFXgprOzb-qbOFu

Comment: I'm not very familar with Torch, I'm and TF guy myself.  That being said I think you can get the memory allocated on device by index:  Replace device with 0 and you will get the memory on device 0 or device 1 if you're doing multi GPU computing. torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0).  PS looks like you're using my answer I would appreciate the 'Accept" answer if you don't mind.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the dtype of the numpy array.

I suspect you have to convert this to 
Change it's dtype

```
torch.from_numpy(np.array(someVar, dtype=np.uint8))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert first from bool to uint8 and then use torch.from_numpy() to get train_y as a torch's Tensor.